# SWIG and windows export macros

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, swig

I am trying to swig a simple C++ class, using Visual Studio 2018 and Python 3.7 and swig 3.0.12. 
My C++ header

```
#ifndef atATObjectH
#define atATObjectH
#include "core/atCoreExporter.h"
#include <string>
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
using std::string;

class AT_CORE ATObject
{
    public:
                                ATObject();
        virtual                 ~ATObject();
        virtual const string    getTypeName() const;
};
#endif
```

The atCoreExporter.h:

```
#ifndef atCoreExporterH
#define atCoreExporterH

#if defined (_WIN32)
    #if defined(AT_STATIC)
        #define AT_CORE
    #else
        #if defined(AT_EXPORT_CORE)
            #define AT_CORE __declspec(dllexport)
        #else
            #define AT_CORE __declspec(dllimport)
        #endif
    #endif
#else
    #define AT_CORE
#endif

#endif
```

I do create a DLL having **AT_EXPORT_CORE** defined.

I'm using CMake to generate the swigged pyd module. This is the interface file:

```
// atexplorer.i
%include "std_string.i"
%include "windows.i"

%module atexplorer
%{
#include "atATObject.h"
%}


//Expose class ATObject to Python
%include "atATObject.h"
```

And here is the CMake file

```
FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(atexplorer.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)

SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY(atexplorer LANGUAGE python SOURCES atexplorer.i)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
.
${ATAPI_ROOT}
${ATAPI_ROOT}/source
${ATAPI_ROOT}/source/core
)

link_directories(${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})

SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES (atexplorer
    atCore
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
)

SET(ATEXPLORER_PACKAGE_DIR site-package)

SET(python_files_path ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/wrappers/python/atexplorer)

INSTALL(
    TARGETS _atexplorer
    DESTINATION ${ATEXPLORER_PACKAGE_DIR}
    COMPONENT python_module
)

INSTALL(
    FILES ${python_files_path}/atexplorer.py __init__.py
    DESTINATION ${ATEXPLORER_PACKAGE_DIR}
    COMPONENT python_module
)
```

The problem I'm having is with export/import macros. The above interface file fails to compile and I get compilation errors from generated SWIG code that looks like this

```
AT_CORE * temp;
temp  = reinterpret_cast< AT_CORE * >(argp);
ATObject = *temp;
```

where AT_CORE is the export/import macro as defined in the atCoreExporter.h above.

Whats the proper solution to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the swig interface file includes the macro header before the macro gets used.  I was able to resolve this by adding a "%include " in the .i file.

```
// atexplorer.i
%include "std_string.i"
%include "windows.i"

%module atexplorer
%{
#include "atATObject.h"
%}

//Expose class ATObject to Python
%include "atCoreExporter.h"
%include "atATObject.h"
```